# Algorithm to find minimum number of bits to distinguish a set of binary numbers

Tags: algorithm, bit

Say we have K binary numbers (each of same length). We need to find minimum of number of bits needed (need not be continuous) to uniquely identify these K binary numbers. For example 100, 110 can be distinguished by 1 bit (at second position). 111, 110, 101 need 2 bits to be distinguished.

Comment: Do you have constraints on the input? Are the numbers 32-bit, 64 bit or arbitrary length? What are the allowed values for K?

Comment: The problem is somewhat related to building a decision tree able to classify the inputs. Maybe take a look at the ID3 algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 3):

We can see those binaries as a set of linear equations. So, for example
, if we have these binary : 1111, 1100, 1001, we can represent them as follow:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = y1
x1 + x2 + 0  + 0  = y2
x1 + 0  + 0  + x4 = y3
```

From here, we realize that, we can use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to reduce those equations to eliminate extra variables (in above example, it is x1). The result of the reduction will be set of K distinct variables, and we remove one extra variable to obtain the result of the original question.

Comment: This will give all the bits that are different. For example in your example this only eliminates one variable where as minimum needed to distinguish is 2.

Comment: @PapudeetBerandhi I have mentioned in my answer, you can always remove one more bit from the Gaussian elimination result to get the final answer.

Comment: @PapudeetBerandhi , Pham, I think misunderstood the question - could you please help me understand how only two bits distinguish `[1111, 1100, 1001]` (and which ones)? Also, how would it be different, in terms of Gaussian elimination as well as the distinguishing bits, if we added `1000` to that example?

Comment: @PhamTrung, consider [1111, 1100, 1001] now these three numbers can be distinguished by bits located at positions 3 and 4 i.e: the last two bits. For [1111, 1100, 1001, 1000] we need three bits to distinguish (the last three). Gaussian eilimation just remove extra bits (like the bit 1 at first position in both the examples) but it does not give us the least number of bits needed..

Comment: @גלעדברקן In order to solve an K-equation system, you can only have K unique variables in the system, otherwise, it is unsolvable. The elimination help you to solve the system, thus, archive the target, as it reduces all equations to a K variables system, with the last row only contains one variable (which also the one you can remove). You can try Gaussian elimination [here](http://matrix.reshish.com/gauss-jordanElimination.php) and verify yourself

Comment: @PapudeetBerandhi don't you need bits 2 and 4 to distinguish between `1100` and `1001`?

Comment: 1100 and 1001 can be distinguished by bits of following combinations 1234, 123,12,2,4,23,24. Any of these combinations can be used to distingish 1100 and 1001

Comment: @Pham nice answer!

Comment: @PapudeetBerandhi oh, I originally thought you meant which bits are needed to show the complete difference between two numbers, so for 1100 and 1001 there are two bits. But what I understand from you now is that you are looking for *any* one bit that's different, which is why you can accept bit 2 or 4 by itself to "distinguish" between the two numbers.

Comment: Exactly, I need the minimum number of bits with which we can show the difference. Any idea?